# how to check if malloc holds the lock

Tags: c++, memory, locking, malloc, signals

I am facing a problem in my code which is as follows:

```
1.A process was using malloc to allocate the memory.
2.While allocation process was interrupted and respective signal handler was 
called. 
3.in the signal handler again malloc was called, which leads to a hang.
```

Now after some googling i came to know that i am not supposed to allocate memory in signal handler.

Is there a way to handle this problem which does not require me to avoid using malloc in signal handler? for e.g. checking if a malloc is already in progress or holds lock.

Comment: use a global flag and update it before first malloc(). In signal handler check this flag before malloc() and act accordingly. However, in this approach races may exist.

Comment: Is the amount you need to allocate fixed? Could you preallocate it at the start of the program?

Comment: @galik, unfortunately no. In my program at run-time depending on some conditions, memory requirement can vary. so it's not possible for me.

Answer (score 3):

Inside of signal handler you can only call [`async-signal-safe functions`](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). `malloc` is not one of them. You may try preallocating memory to be used in signal handler in advance (before installing signal handler) though.